# error: expected identifier or '(' before 'try' objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, try-catch

When i use @try @catch, i get error: expected identifier or '(' before 'try' objective-c

```
@implementation BannerView
 @synthesize timer;

@synthesize _responceInfo;
@synthesize recivedData;

@try {
NSString* const _mainUrl = 
@"http://www.admobilapp.com/view.php?place_id=15&country_id=112&sex=3&rand=0.7858213884755969&gsmOperator=";
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
}

NSString*const _ImagePath= @"\"image\":";
NSString*const _ImageClickUrl= @"\"link\":";
NSString*const _imagerotation = @"\"rotation\":";
```

How to fix it?

error: expected identifier or '(' before 'try' objective-c, fixed, but now if i run application i have another error,
And app is crash.

2012-02-27 00:28:02.794 Clicky[8409:9203] finally
2012-02-27 00:28:02.818 Clicky[8409:9203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '** -[NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db1be9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f065c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6a628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6a59a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   Foundation                          0x000250de -[NSString substringFromIndex:] + 133
    5   Clicky                              0x00003232 -[BannerView ExtractStringKeyValue:] + 123
    6   Clicky                              0x000031b1 -[BannerView ExtractImageUrl] + 48
    7   Clicky                              0x00003739 -[BannerView Refresh] + 59
    8   Clicky                              0x00003805 -[BannerView initWithFrame:] + 157
    9   UIKit                               0x0049fce5 +[UIButton buttonWithType:] + 1373
    10  Clicky                              0x00002e6a -[Examples viewDidLoad] + 51
    11  UIKit                               0x0036865e -[UIViewController view] + 179
    12  UIKit                               0x0037b230 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 120
    13  UIKit                               0x00379d86 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
    14  UIKit                               0x0037bb7e -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263
    15  UIKit                               0x0037b9ed -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 352
    16  UIKit                               0x002baa6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    17  UIKit                               0x004b81f2 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 422
    18  UIKit                               0x002baa6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    19  UIKit                               0x003491b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    20  UIKit                               0x0034b647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    21  UIKit                               0x0034916c -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49
    22  UIKit                               0x002baa6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    23  UIKit                               0x003491b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    24  UIKit                               0x0034b647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    25  UIKit                               0x0034a1f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    26  UIKit                               0x002df0d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    27  UIKit                               0x002c037a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    28  UIKit                               0x002c5732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x016e7a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00d93064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf36f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf0983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf0240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf0161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x016e6268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x016e632d GSEventRun + 115
    37  UIKit                               0x002c942e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    38  Clicky                              0x00002840 main + 102
    39  Clicky                              0x000027d1 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exception

@try @catch doesn't work. :(.

Comment: Post the code before this. The error is not here.

Comment: Is this code in a method?  Or is it just hanging out all by itself in the implementation?

Comment: @Peter M I thought the same thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `@try/@catch/@finally` outside a method body. Assigning a static string cannot fail anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write code outside of methods.